# difference between /bin/sh and /bin/bash(chrooted)

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, permissions, python

I am stuck in this issue:

I have a new server which i access thru ssh, using PuTTy. In Configuration, i need to select which ssh shell i need in order to access  the server with ssh.

choices:

```
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/bin/dash
/bin/bash(chrooted)
```

If i choose `/bin/sh`, I dont have the some permissions e.g. to install setuptools of python, If I choose `/bin/bash(chrooted)`, I dont have python and if I python it says: command not found.

I am using Debian 7,

what should i do?

Comment: What do you mean by "In Configuration"? Who is asking you to make this choice? By "server", do you mean an account on a hosting provider, or do you really have control over the whole server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the purpose of the server ?

Do you want users to have limited access or not ?

In you want to use it as a normal server it's better to use bash.
Chroot is actually a stripped  environment (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)
Used in cases that you want users to access only a few commands and just that {for example in gateways}

It highly depends on what you want to do.
The default /general behavior is to choose /bin/bash